# Unable to save main Jenkins configuration?

Tags: java, jenkins

On saving main configuration Jenkins throws the following errors:

```
2021-07-08 07:07:08.373+0000 [id=445578]        WARNING o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler$Context#log: Error while serving https://jenkins.mydomain.co.uk/configSubmit
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.ApacheAsyncHttpClient.lambda$doExecute$4(ApacheAsyncHttpClient.java:344)
Caused: com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponseTransformationException
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.DefaultResponseTransformation$DefaultResponseTransformationBuilder.lambda$defaultThrowableHandler$1(DefaultResponseTransformation.java:202)
        at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises.lambda$biFunction$7(Promises.java:424)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:811)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1.lambda$doFailed$1(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:42)
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:61)
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:129)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

and

````
      2021-07-08 07:07:08.374+0000 [id=445578]        WARNING h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID 70efab92-035a-49e6-b5c0-27a04ccd8859
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.ApacheAsyncHttpClient.lambda$doExecute$4(ApacheAsyncHttpClient.java:344)
Caused: com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponseTransformationException
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.DefaultResponseTransformation$DefaultResponseTransformationBuilder.lambda$defaultThrowableHandler$1(DefaultResponseTransformation.java:202)
        at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises.lambda$biFunction$7(Promises.java:424)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:811)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1.lambda$doFailed$1(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:42)
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:61)
        at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:129)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:816)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)```
````

I am not quite sure if anything changed because Jenkins was not updated for 4-5 months and last time configuration change did work well. Weird thing is that Jenkins config.xml has the changes on disk but when I restart Jenkins they take no effect.
This is my Jenkins version info:

```
     Jul 08, 2021 8:22:10 AM INFO hudson.WebAppMain contextInitialized
     Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: 
     SystemProperties.getProperty("JENKINS_HOME")
Jul 08, 2021 8:22:10 AM INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
Started w.@895e367{Jenkins v2.263.4,/,file:///var/cache/jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/cache/jenkins/war}
Jul 08, 2021 8:22:10 AM INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
Started ServerConnector@2f686d1f{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:8080}
Jul 08, 2021 8:22:10 AM INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
Started @1493ms
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns issue was due to Jira plugin in version v3.2.1.
Upgrade to v.3.3 solved the issue.